# Limit of inner product of vectors of $\ell^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, limits

Let $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be the canonical basis for $\ell^2$. Let
$$
P= \left[\begin{array}{cccc} 1 \\ & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2!}} \\ && \frac{1}{\sqrt{3!}} \\ &&&\ddots \end{array}\right], \ \
\alpha_n = \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{\sqrt 2}e_n + \frac{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt 2}e_{n+1}, \ \ \textrm{and} \ \ Q = \left[\begin{array}{cccc} 0&1\\&0&1\\&&0&\ddots\\&&&\ddots
\end{array}\right].
$$
I want to compute
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow +\infty}\langle PQ\alpha_n\;, \;PQ\alpha_n\rangle \;.$$
Thank you.

Comment: Why?${{{{{{}}}}}}$

Comment: Because I want to use this example in the construction of a counter example, but I'm facing difficulties in the computing of this limit

Comment: In none of your five questions do you show your working so far. This is rude & frowned upon. Currently, you are abusing the site. Please stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q$ is a "demotion" operator $$Qe_n = e_{n-1}$$

Hence $$Qa_n = \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{\sqrt{2}}e_{n-1} + \frac{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt{2}}e_{n}$$ and $$Pe_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}e_n$$ thus $$PQa_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2}}e_{n-1} + \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{2}}e_{n}$$

So basically your limit is $\infty$.